# How to change text in the same area when hover over images with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the texts when I hover over image, but I can't solve this problem. This problem makes me crazy. Each image has different texts. When hover over an image, text for that image will appear on the text box.
For describing the topic, I'm giving here an image:
see the image on this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZKwn.png)

I'm giving my HTML and CSS code in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tahsinabrar/X8dwn/2/)
Also giving the HTML and CSS code here:
HTML Code:

```
        <div id="tabbox">
            <div id="tab1">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/240X240">
                <div class="tabcontent">
                    <p>Text box to describe the images around when you hover over them, this description will change depending on what image you hover over.</p>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="tab2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/240X240">
                <div class="tabcontent">
                    <p>Another text comes here for hover the mouse on the image.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS Code here:

```
    #tabbox{
    width: 90%;
    height: 380px;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #888;
}

#tabbox img{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;

}

.tabcontent{
    padding:10px 0 0 40px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #000;  
    left:0;
    top:40px;
    height:120px;
    display:block;
    margin-top:40px;
    transition: all 1.2s;
}

#tab1{
float: left;
}

#tab2 {
float: left;
left: 250px;
width: 480px;
}

#tab1.tabcontent{
            z-index:2;
            background:#fff;
        }

#tab1 img{
            z-index:3;
            width:240px;
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            cursor:hand;
            background:#fff;

}

#tab2.tabcontent{
            z-index:1; 
            opacity:0;
        }

#tab2 img{
    width:220px;
    position:absolute;
    left:260px;
    top:0;
    cursor:hand;
    background: #ddd;
}

    #tabbox:hover img, #tabs:focus img, #tabs:active img{
        background:none;
        z-index:0;
        }

    #tabbox:hover .tabcontent, #tabs:focus .tabcontent, #tabs:active .tabcontent{
        z-index:0;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition : opacity .75s ease-in;
        }

    #tab1:hover img,#tab1:focus img,#tab1:active img{z-index:4;background:#fff;}
    #tab1:hover .tabcontent,#tab1:focus .tabcontent,#tab1:active .tabcontent{   z-index:3;  background:#fff; opacity:1; -webkit-transition : opacity 500ms ease-in;}

    #tab2:hover img,#tab2:focus img,#tab2:active img{z-index:4;background:#fff;}
    #tab2:hover .tabcontent,#tab2:focus .tabcontent,#tab2:active .tabcontent{   z-index:3;  background:#fff; opacity:1; -webkit-transition : opacity 500ms ease-in;}
```

If you check my code, you'll understand the problem. Please anybody help me on this topic.

Comment: The static layout seems all messed up.  Why don't you get that working first before you worry about dynamic stuff?

Comment: I'm new in Stackoverflow. I didn't understand what you meant by "static layout". Which one did you indicate?

Comment: I mean what you have looks messed up even before there are any changes due to mouse hovering.

Comment: That was the main problem. I did all things, but I couldn't re-organize this. At this point, I messed all things! Zane M. helps me to solve this problem. Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the selector you are looking for is `#tab1:hover > .tabcontent`

Try updating `.tabcontent` to

```
.tabcontent{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding:10px 0 0 40px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #000;  
    left:0;
    top:40px;
    height:120px;
    display:block;
    margin-top:40px;
    transition: all 1.2s;
}
```

Then add the selector

```
#tab1:hover > .tabcontent, #tab2:hover >.tabcontent
{
     display: block;
}
```

Here is a fiddle that fixes the layout (I guessed about how you wanted things positioned) as well as changes the `#tab1` and `#tab2` Ids and selectors to `.tab` for better scalability and requiring less CSS selectors. I removed some attributes for simplification.
http://jsfiddle.net/DLBPF/